# Left-hand side and right-hand side in multiple assignment

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding these two sections in ruby-doc:

- [Implicit Array Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment)
- [Multiple Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)

When it says left-hand side, the splat operator is on the right side, and when it says right-hand side, the operator is on the left side. For example:

> The `*` can appear anywhere on the right-hand side:
>
> ```
> *a, b = 1, 2, 3
> p a: a, b: b # prints {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>3}
> ```

Can anyone explain me what the meaning of left-hand side and right-hand side is in these sections? To me, examples seem contradictory.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa, what does left hand side and right hand side mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a mistake in this v2.0.0 reference manual. Your understanding is correct.

Both have been fixed in the v2.2.0 manual ([Implicit Array Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment) and [Multiple Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)).

Comment: Thanks, I think the second one is also completely fixed, my example is modified from `The * can appear anywhere on the right-hand side:` to `The * can appear anywhere on the left-hand side:`

Comment: @Ashkan Right, I must have been looking at it wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is supposed to mean what you have in mind. However, the document looks like it has mistakes. You can report this to the developers [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/issues) as a documentation bug.

Comment: That's from an old version of Ruby. Actually, it has already been fixed in the current version.

Answer (score -1):

`*` will turn an argument list in to an array and visa versa:

```
def do_it(*args)
  args
end

do_it(1, 'hello') # => [1, 'hello']
```

In the case of `*a, b = 1, 2, 3` it is processed right to left, `b` is assigned `3` and the remaining arguments, `2` and `3` to `a` as an array, `[2, 3]`.

In the case of `a = 1, *[2,3]`, the array, `[2, 3]`, is converted to arguments `2, 3`. Therefore equivalent to `a = 1, 2, 3`.

Why `a = 1, 2, 3` is valid and does not cause an error I do not know. I would guess, Ruby does an implicit splat when you supply multiple arguments to a single var assignment. So `a = [1, 2, 3]` is functionaly the same as `a = 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: The question is not about how the splat or multiple assignment works. The question is about what the terms "left-hand side" and "right-hand side" used in the documentation are supposed to mean.